# Hide rows in Google Sheets if Column B is empty and not 0?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used the script provided by [JPV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889423/jpv) for hiding rows if a cell in column B is empty in that row:

```
function onEdit() {

var sheets = ["MyProgress"];
for (var i = 0, sLen = sheets.length; i < sLen; i++) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName(sheets[i])
    var val = sheet.getRange('B:B')
        .getValues();
    for (var j = 0, vLen = val.length; j < vLen; j++) {
      sheet.showRows(j + 1)
        if (!val[j][0]) sheet.hideRows(j + 1)
        }
    }



}
```

The problem is that this code also hides a row if the data in cell B contains the number '0'

Can anyone help/improve this answer please?

PS: values in the column are obtained from another cell (formatted as a percentage):

```
=iferror(AZ2/CX2,)
```

And values in AZ and CX columns are obtained as a query:

```
=transpose(QUERY(Task!$B$3:$E$10011,"Select E where B='"& A2 &"'",0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to avoid hiding the row if the cell is 0, so you should add a strict comparison to check that. You should add this condition to your `if` statement:

`val[j][0] !== 0`

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 0):

Because the `!0` and `!''` is have the same result is true at the condition

```
if (!val[j][0]) sheet.hideRows(j + 1)
```

So you just simply add one more condition to skip the value `0`

```
if (!val[j][0] && val[j][0] != 0) sheet.hideRows(j + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Phat, that doesn't hide the rows at all unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, not ideal I've used is this (using FILTERS). Cumbersome to edit data into another sheet though since it keeps flicking to/from sheets:

```
  function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("MyProgress");

  first.activate();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  var second = ss.getSheetByName("Task");
  second.activate();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Phat Tran Ky proposal almost got the thing done, but was missing an equal in this condition `val[j][0] != 0`.

So try changing this:

```
if (!val[j][0]) sheet.hideRows(j + 1)
```

For this:

```
if (!val[j][0] && val[j][0] !== 0) sheet.hideRows(j + 1)
```